# IE11 adds &nbsp; before img src tag

Tags: jquery, html, ckeditor, kcfinder

I'm using CKEditor (KCFinder for image upload) on a CRUD system I'm building. When my images are saved they show up correctly in FF / Chrome / Safari. Once I check IE11 the images are not loading properly. Upon further inspection, I've found the src attribute has a prepended Nonbreaking Space. So it looks like:

```
<img &nbsp;src="blah.jpg" />
```

Any help on this would be awesome as I've tried numerous solutions and have been googling for a lengthy bit of time now.

(PHP replace &nbsp and  src, removing style attribute altogether when images are saved)